# Automatically indent align enum parameters in columns (table-like) in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, indentation

Say I have an enum like this:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TEST1(5, 6, 18, 9, 3),
    TEST2(10, 21, 4, 5, 34),
    TEST3(4, 5, 8, 2, 16),
    TEST4(3, 1, 92, 67, 22);

    TestEnum(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5) {
    }
}
```

How can I automatically (or by clicking `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L`) format the enum like this:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TEST1   (5,     6,      18,     9,      3),
    TEST2   (10,    21,     4,      5,      34),
    TEST3   (4,     5,      8,      2,      16),
    TEST4   (3,     1,      92,     67,     22);
    
    TestEnum(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5) {
    }
}
```

It should optimally use tabs, so that the columns start at indexes divisible by 4 (0, 4, 8, 12 ...)

---

I tried these workarounds:

- Formatting myself using `@formatter:off`, which is

  - a lot of work
  - disables all kinds of formatting like lambda arguments and double spaces

I tried these settings:

- This setting, which did not do anything:

> Settings/Editor/Code Style/Detect and use existing file indents for editing

- This setting, which only works for fields, variables, assignments and simple methods. It doesn't seem to exist for Kotlin:

> Settings/Editor/Code Style/Java/Wrapping and Braces/Group declarations

I tried these plugins:

- [Vertical Align](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13382) goes into the right direction, but doesn't solve the problem either. It still isn't automatic and doesn't work together with code formatting at all: When pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L`, the code goes back to normal
- Same thing for [Smart Align](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13903), and commas are also being aligned, which looks very weird
- [Edit] Same thing for [Column Align](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14274). It is glitched, but doesn't have any other compatibility issues (works in Kotlin, Android Studio and with enums)
- [Tabifier](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/178) is old and thus doesn't work on Android
- [Java Code Aligner](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17939) neither works for Kotlin nor enums

Edit:

As suggested by [quickfix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18430882), I added a [YouTrack suggestion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-298519).

Comment: I don't think it's possible atm. You can file a feature request for "Group declarations" to be appleid to enums and Kotlin in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA